# 'flyway-play' does not find/connect to a database that Slick has no problems connecting to

Tags: scala, playframework, database-migration, slick, flyway

I want to use Flyway (flyway-play) to do db migrations.

I have absolutely no problems connecting to the database with Slick, making queries and inserting new data etc.
However, I can not get Flyway to work with it.

When I visit `http://localhost:9000/@flyway/postgres` endpoint I get `database postgres not found`. And in fact on `http://localhost:9000/@flyway` I can see that there are no databases detected.

I have prepared migrations and placed them in the `conf\db\migration\postgres` folder.

This is my configuration for the `postgres` database:

```
slick {
  dbs {
    postgres {
      driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
      db {
        profile = org.postgresql.Driver
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"${db-name}
        user = ${db-user}
        password = ${db-password}
        connectionPool = disabled
        keepAliveConnection = true
        autoCommit = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my `DatabaseProvider`:

```
package database.config

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider
import play.db.NamedDatabase
import slick.jdbc.{JdbcProfile, PostgresProfile}

@Singleton
final class DatabaseProvider @Inject()(@NamedDatabase("postgres") configProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  val dbConfig = configProvider.get[PostgresProfile]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@vdebergue thanks for pointing in the right direction, I got it to work.

I moved my my migrations into `conf\db\migration\default` folder and tweaked `application.conf` a little so it looks like this:

```
db {
    default = ${slick.dbs.postgres.db}
    default.migration.locations=["common","postgres"]
}

slick {
  dbs {
    postgres {
      driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
      db {
        profile = org.postgresql.Driver
        driver = ${slick.dbs.postgres.db.profile} // required for Flyway
        url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/"${db-name}
        user = ${db-user}
        password = ${db-password}
        connectionPool = disabled
        keepAliveConnection = true
        autoCommit = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but it seems that the flyway plugin expects the database configuration to be under `db.{dbname}` and following the [default config](https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play/blob/master/plugin/src/main/scala/org/flywaydb/play/ConfigReader.scala#L73)

You can try to add this to your `application.conf`:

```
db.default = ${slick.dbs.postgres.db}
db.default.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
```